# How to get the different image sizes needed for a UIImage in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I am creating an app and I need the different image sizes needed for `UIImage`s in Xcode.

The issue that I have is I am allocating the image to my `UIImage` but the different image sizes seem to take over the cell.

My simulator:

[image]

My view controller:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to get the different image sizes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you really want to achieve with an example? Personally, I really don't have the ability of reading people's minds.

Comment: When I add an image, I need to drag the image from finder to the `assets.images` folder in my project. You need different image sizes of the image so it supports different iOS devices. I was wondering how you get the different image sizes (1x, 2x, 3x) that are needed. @ozgur

Comment: This is a repeat of your last question which you deleted. You have to create images of the proper size. It's that simple.

Comment: @rmaddy I did this but when I run my app, the image has spread across the whole cell, not in its allocated UIImage space. I will add a picture to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy Don't worry, I fixed the issue. It was because I didn't add the width and height constraints to the image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the width and height constraints to the image view.

Answer (score -1):

Just use size property of UIImage Class. It needs CGSize...like CGSize(1920, 1280)

Comment: I want to scale it without the use of code. When I add the images to `xassets.images`, I want them to fit in the universal (1x, 2x, 3x) image sizes.